# How to filter table using dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, filtering, dropdown

So I've been learning Laravel for the past 4 days and I'm trying to start a new Laravel project. So the problem is I want to filter my table with a dropdown, can anyone tell me how to do it using Javascript?

heres the table

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-rincian horizontal-scrollable">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 10%">Kode</th>
                    <th scope="col">Uraian</th>
                    <th scope="col">Volume</th>
                    <th scope="col">Satuan</th>
                    <th scope="col">Harga</th>
                    <th scope="col">Jumlah</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ket</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:15% !important;">Aksi</th>
                    <th scope="col">Catatan</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table-group-divider">

                @php

                $array = json_decode( $listrabrincian, true );

                $arrays = $array['rab_rincian'];
       
                foreach($arrays as $item) {

                    

                    echo "

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        ";
                            echo $item['kode_akun'];
                            echo "
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ";
                            echo $item['uraian'];
                            echo "
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ";
                            echo $item['volum'];
                            echo "
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ";
                            echo $item['satuan'];
                            echo "
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ";
                            echo $item['sbm'];
                            echo "
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ";
                            echo $item['subtotal'];
                            echo "
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            -
                        </td>
                       
                        <td>                                                        
                                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>EDIt</button>
                                

                                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' type='button'  data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#btn_i_copy'>
                                COPY
                                </button>

                                 <button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' type='button'  data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#btn_i_delete'>
                                HAPUS
                                </button>
                                                              
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            -

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    ";

                }

                    @endphp
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and heres the dropdown, I want this dropdown to filter the "kode_akun" from the table

```
<select name="dd_akun" id="ddAkun" style="width: 70%;" >
            <option value="">All</option>
                @php

                $array = json_decode( $listakun, true );

                $arrays = $array['akun'];

                foreach($arrays as $item) {

                    $kode = $item['kode'];
                    $uraian = $item['uraian'];
                    echo "<option value='$kode'> $uraian </option>";
                }
                @endphp
            
        
            </select>
```

Comment: If the json data that is used to build the table was fetched a single time and saved within a javascript variable then you could filter that json data quickly and modify the displayed data accordingly with some basic javascript.

Comment: Might https://datatables.net/ help?

Comment: I see no attempt to do any filtering here. Where is your Javascript? Where is your controller method doing any filtering? Also if you have to use `@php` you're not using Laravel correctly. Never do logic in a view, never use `echo` in a view.